# spark: get combination of huge data to generate an edge set for GraphX

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, relationship, spark-graphx

I'm using spark GraphX to build a graph of wifi relationship.
The vertex is user ID.
The edge is true if two users have connected a same wifi

Now I have a huge rdd:RDD[(U,V)].
The key of rdd is wifi ID, value is a set of all users who have connected this wifi.
(The biggest wifi have 50,000 users. The smallest wifi have 3 users. The distinct number of total user is 10,000,000. All wifi is 2,000,000)

I have to build an edge set if two user have connected a same wifi.

Now I using cartesian in spark, but it is too slow(Maybe several weeks) and spend too many memory.

How can I resolve it? I 
Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you provide a code sample how you compute the cartesian on each set?
Generally, you will have a problem of accessing each of the sets individually. Aside from that, should it be a multi-graph (i.e. should each _different_ set of wifi IDs between users result in another edge)?